# Bound the number of vertices on the convex hull of a self cartesian product

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hulls

Given a finite set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $n$ elements. One can construct a set $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the cartesian product: $B = A \times  A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Is there any tight bound of the number of vertices on the convex hull of $B$?

Comment: Let the points in $A$ be $a_1 < \dots < a_n$. The points on the convex hull are precisely those of the form $(a_1, a_i), (a_n, a_i), (a_i, a_1), (a_i, a_n)$, and there are $4n - 2$ such points. Did you mean to ask a different question? (The generalization of this seems related to Shearer's lemma)